# How to configure kally-razor with express nodejs?

Tags: node.js, razor, express

A razor view engine for nodejs.
https://github.com/nufyoot/kally-razor

I have tried something like this.. but no luck.

```
var razor = kallyrazor({
    root: __dirname + '/views/',
    layout: 'shared/layout.html'
});
app.engine('html', function (path, options, fn) {
    fn(null, razor.render(path, options));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me. Did you include the view engine?

**app.set('view engine', 'cshtml');**

Note: I chose the use the cshtml extentionm just for vanity.. (And also in Sublime if that is your editor the razor syntax highlighter, https://github.com/joseph-turner/Razor)

Full code:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var KallyRazor = require('kally-razor');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'cshtml'); // NOTE THE VIEW ENGINE
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Setup KallyRazor
var razor = KallyRazor({
    root: __dirname + '/views/',
    layout: '/shared/layout.cshtml'
});

app.engine('cshtml', function (path, options, fn) {
    fn(null, razor.render(path, options));
});

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```